# unable to 'click' on adverts

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have the following in my applicationDidFinishLaunching method:

```
ADBannerView* iAdView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
iAdView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:iAdView];
```

Ads are visible but I can't click on any of them.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Check out these links, it seems you don't know about all the delegate methods and setup iAd actually needs.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Reference/iAd_ReferenceCollection/_index.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/

Answer (score 1):

If you see a blank white box and an unhandled error in your console ("no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveWithError"), then the touch isn't working because no ad has been received yet. You'll need to implement the delegate method if you want to handle the receive error.

If you wait a while, an ad will probably appear. Then you'll be able to interact with it. If not, it's possible that you haven't signed up for the iAd program yet in iTunes Connect.